# Angularjs not redirecting after login

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, redirect

I am using Angular.js `$http.post` to login user.

This is what I do on `.success`:

```
$window.location.href = "/dummy"
```

Dummy is simple redirect back to `/` (as it seemd to not reload the page when I was redirecting to `/` while I was there).

I am using two layouts `index.html` and `home.html`. While `index.html` is landing page, `home.html` is after-login page. `/` is then controlled by cookies from login.

When redirected from either of two, most of the time I get stuck at the same page (even when I F5). Everything is ok after Shift-F5 which I believe is hard reload.

Server is correctly returning layouts (also after redirect), but browser seems to be ignoring that.

Is it possible this is just localhost issue?

Tried newest chrome, opera and IE.

Comment: You should use `$location` service, try `$location.path('/dummy')`

Comment: This is ending on `localhost:/#/dummy` which is angular path that won't even reload the page. I need to reload it to get the second one (because login will set the cookie which will cause server to send `home.html` instead of `index.html`)